# How to default font family, font size and line spacing in TinyMce?

Tags: tinymce

How to change default **font family** , **font size** and **line spacing** in TinyMce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create a **StyleSheet.css** file and placed into **CSS** folder of your project.

2.put following style into **StyleSheet.css**

```
body
{
  font-family:Tahoma;
  font-size:11.5pt;
  line-height:100%;
}
```

3. Add follwing code to  **tinymce.init**

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
     content_css: "/CSS/StyleSheet.css",
    ...
});
```